# Do stories about a Batman-like character exist in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel

Reading through an old issue of *Black Panther*, I came across this panel:

[image]
(from [*Black Panther (1998) #56*](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/12625/black_panther_1998_55)).

This is a pretty obvious reference to Batman villains Penguin and Riddler; it's not even a bit subtle.

Is this just a one-off gag written into this issue, or have other Marvel characters made references to fictional (within the universe) characters that are obviously meant to be Batman, or other DC heroes/villains?

Comment: I don't have a reference right now, but I remember in one episode of the 90s Spider-Man Saturday morning cartoon, Spider-Man is being interviewed by a little girl who's a huge fan of his.  At one point, she asks where he came from, and says that she's heard he's the last survivor of a dying planet.  He says no, that's a different superhero.

Comment: I recall Peter Parker getting fed up with the Daily Bugle (or more specifically, it's editor) and selling photos to the Daily Planet. He went back to the Bugle because the Planet was too nosy about how he got such great Spider-Man pictures.

Comment: I've heard some people refer to Daredevil as "Marvel's Batman".  Not official of course (hence comment instead of answer), but he is kind of the same sort of dark-hero.  No actual superpowers (just heightened awareness and fighting skills), fights best at night (because of blindness in his case), has Gothic inclinations (hangs out on the roofs of cathedrals), very public alter-ego (high-stakes lawyer), usually a low gravelly voice.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Why yes, yes they do:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The occasional inter-universe joke or reference is common. Same happens DC to Marvel.

Of note, both Marvel and DC main universes, exist inside the other's multiverse (I'm not sure about New 52). Marvel Comics and DC Comics exist in the Marvel Universe as real companies, the former being legal, licensed retellings of Marvel events (Like Inception), and the latter a normal comic company. Aside from in-universe crossovers, Clark Kent and Lois seem to be an actual (probably normal human) reporters.

[image]

Comment: What issue is the Iron Man/Kitty Pryde bit from?

Comment: @cjm A+X #2. And as a counterpoint, Xmen Legacy #267.

Comment: Another example: in Avengers #93 (from the Kree-Skrull War), Ant-Man enters a malfunctioning Vision and comments: *"What it looks like is a leftover movie set from Metropolis. Fritz Lang’s, not Clark Kent’s! Just the place for an old E.C. fan-addict like me!"*

Answer (score 5):

While not exactly what you're asking about, I'd be remiss if I didn't mention the Squadron Supreme.  They're essentially [a Marvel version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Squadron_Supreme_members) of DC's Justice League:

- Hyperion - Superman
- Nighthawk - Batman
- Power Princess - Wonder Woman

and so on.  Many of their villains are similarly mimicking Justice League villains.  They're not native to the mainline Earth-616 continuity, they're from Earth-712 (or at least the most common version of them is, *comic books are whacky*), but they're often interacting with other universes in the Marvel multiverse.  For exmaple, there's a Hyperion in the *Avengers* book that just ended recently when *Secret Wars* started.

Comment: I *highly* recommend the 1980's *Squadron Supreme* 12 issue miniseries.  It explores some of the 'what if superheroes were real' ground that stuff like *Watchmen* and *Justice League Unlimited* explored.

Comment: Yeah I knew about Hyperion being basically Marvel Superman, didn't know about the others yet.

Comment: Yes! I was very much reminded of the parallelism especially when I saw this in the Avengers Assemble series...

Answer (score 5):

In the past, I remember reading a cross-over with Batman and Spiderman.

So after some searching I found the comic:

http://marvel.wikia.com/Spider-Man_and_Batman_Vol_1_1

Comment: This story does not occur in any of the main universes (616 or ultimate).

Comment: @phantom42: true, but that was not a restriction in the question. So I think this is a good answer.