# Does Marvel Comics exist in the the DC universe?

Tags: marvel, dc, reference

We know from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/93023/51226) that DC Comics, or at least some of its properties, exist in the Marvel Universe.

Is the reverse true? Have any DC comics shown or implied that Marvel Comics, or any of its properties, exist in any of the DC universes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The *Multiversity* series (DC New 52) has "Major Comics"

I can't find any evidence of Marvel Comics or any of its properties existing as fictional media within the DC Universe.  Of course, there have been various cross-overs and cameos in which a character from Marvel appears flesh and blood in the DC Universe.  But as far as I can find, there are no discussions of Marvel characters as *fiction* in DC comics.  (*It's difficult to prove a negative, and I will be happy if someone proves me wrong!*)

That being said, in the *Multiversity* limited series (DC New 52), there is reference to a comic book publishing house by the name of ***Major Comics***, responsible for the properties *The Retaliators*, *Crusader*, and *Lord Havok*, which are largely agreed to be references to *The Avengers*, *Captain America*, and *Doctor Doom*, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I've readed first tome of Sandman several days ago, and there's one point where a character complains about his former girlfriend tooking away all his stuff, including his "Silver Surfers".

In the moment I readed it I got surprised by such a direct comment. Maybe Silver Surfer can refers to anything different than the comic? English is not my native language and I don't know if this expression can refer to something different.